# Mute console text input

Tags: node.js, terminal, console, stdin, stdio

My **process.stdin** is set to RAW mode, so I can catch user keypress event with:

```
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
     // process keypress      
});
```

Events are successfully fired, keystrokes registered, but I haven't been able to find a way to prevent input to console. Using this approach, is it possible to prevent a key to be written to console? If not, is there any other way to intercept keypress event without sending keystrokes to console?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_three_states

Comment: @Darth I read the docs you linked and I managed to block the input by setting process.stdin.readableFlowing = null; but this unfortunately prevents the "keypress" event from being fired. is there a way to keep it working without actually inputting to console?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided miss some more details.
As it is it should not output anything to the console.

But let's say you did something like this :

```
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
    console.log(key);
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

This will output :

- the key object if the key pressed has no displayable char. i.e :

```
 {
  sequence: ' ',
  name: 'space',
  ctrl: false,
  meta: false,
  shift: false
}
```

- otherwise it will output the key pressed char followed by the key object:

```
a{ sequence: 'a', name: 'a', ctrl: false, meta: false, shift: false }
```

If what you want to do is to avoid the keypressed char from being displayed you can try this :

```
var readline = require('readline');
var Writable = require('stream').Writable;

var mutableStdout = new Writable({
  write: function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (!this.muted)
      process.stdout.write(chunk, encoding);
    callback();
  }
});

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: mutableStdout,
  terminal: true
});
```

What we do here basically is to define a readline interface with a mutable output stream so now we can use these instructions:

- `mutableStdout.muted = true;` to mute the output stream of the readline interface 
  this prevents default outputs to affect console in raw mode. 
  note that you can still ouput in console using either `console.log()` or `process.stdout.write()`
- `mutableStdout.muted = false;` to unmute the output stream of the readline interface

If we now take the first example and turn it into this :

```
var readline = require('readline');
var Writable = require('stream').Writable;

var mutableStdout = new Writable({
  write: function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (!this.muted)
      process.stdout.write(chunk, encoding);
    callback();
  }
});

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: mutableStdout,
  terminal: true
});

process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
    console.log(key);
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();

mutableStdout.muted = true; //
```

What was giving this result before: 
`a{ sequence: 'a', name: 'a', ctrl: false, meta: false, shift: false }`

will now give that : 
`{ sequence: 'a', name: 'a', ctrl: false, meta: false, shift: false }`

**Now about the way to get more convenient keypress events** 
 what about turning the original `process.stdin.on('keypress',)` into a console events emitter himself.

Just like this:

```
const event = require('events');
let event_ = new event.EventEmitter();

process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
    event_.emit('keyPressed', {key: key});
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

Using `event_` you can now listen to the keypress from anywhere inside your program.

here is an example :

```
event_.on('keyPressed', (e) => {
   key = e.key; 
   console.log(`${key.name} pressed`);
});
```

with this every time a key is pressed it should log the message:

```
 keyName pressed
```

or

```
 undefined pressed
```

if the key pressed has no name attribute.

For more informations on how to use those console events you could check this post on the nodejs website : [What are Event Emitters?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-event-emitters/)

Basically you can nearly do the same stuff with the console events that what you can do with events in a web navigator.